# Create a full duplex replication among two MySQL servers

Tags: mysql, replication

Already configured **Master-Slave Replication** among *two different machines*. Now the problem is that it only allows the *Master to enter the data and Slave to view this*. the changes which made in Slave is not reflected in master.

My question is that is it possible to **create a full duplex replication among two MySQL servers**.  ie, If i change the data either in master or in Slave both will reflected in both the machines.

References:

- [MySQL Master-Slave Replication](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Replication)
- [Steps to configure Master-Slave Replication](http://www.vxcompany.info/2012/07/14/implement-mysql-replication-in-3-simple-steps/)

Comment: may i know what is the reason for -1?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the downvote, there's bound to be someone out there who didn't think you asked the right question, or that you're asking about how to do something that they don't think you should try. Just remember: *illegitimi non carborundum.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but there are risks, because replications is asynchronous. That is, both servers could insert the same row, and then when they process the replication log from the other server, they get a conflict.

You can listen to more about this problem in this free webinar: [The Hazards of Multi-writing in a Dual-Master Setup](http://www.percona.com/webinars/hazards-multi-writing-dual-master-setup)

You should consider using a cluster solution with synchronous replication, like [Percona XtraDB Cluster](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtradb-cluster).